# document.getElementById("id").value = ""; Not working

Tags: getelementbyid

The code for example `document.getElementById("id").value="value";` is not working. I have assigned it on a function to replace the current value of the textbox once the page is loaded.

here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function rplace(){
 document.getElementById('idtext').value="New Value";
}
onload=rplace
 </script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="idtext" name="idtext" value="">
</form>
```

Comment: That example should work. You should qualify `onload` as `window.onload` presuming that what you intend.

Comment: when do you call the rplace function ?

Comment: Are you sure the function is even running? as other comments have suggested using onload would actually call the function (unless you are referring to it elsewhere?)

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers, it seems that there is an error regarding the ID that is generated by Infusionsoft. I just changed the ID and its ok now. THanks :)

Answer (score 2):

use jquery insteat of javascript.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ $("#idtext").val("New Value")});
```

Refer [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-get-set-form-values/)

Comment: Oh wait... jQuery instead of JavaScript... Sure, jQuery is written in C++, I see...

Comment: Thanks for all your Answers, it seems that there is an error regarding the ID that is generated by Infusionsoft. I just changed the ID and its ok now. THanks :)